# I want to display data from AlertDialog with an editText and then display it to a list view it'snot working, this is my code

Tags: android

```
package com.example.riplee07.trydialog;

import android.app.AlertDialog;

import android.content.DialogInterface;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.EditText;

import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;




public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    ArrayList<String> listss = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter <String>adapter;

    String add1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText tt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        final ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        Button br = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        add1 = tt.getText().toString();


        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listss);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        listss.add(add1);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        br.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                View ss = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.textt,null);
               final AlertDialog.Builder builderDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

                builderDialog.setView(ss)
                        .setPositiveButton("Print", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                listss.add(add1);
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            }
                        }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                        .setCancelable(false);

                AlertDialog alert = builderDialog.create();
                alert.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Explain the purpose and contents of `R.layout.textt`.

Comment: it's an another layout that contains one editText that is shown in the alertDialog.

Comment: You aren't really using the Edittext in that layout then...Post the xml

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>

Comment: Use the 'edit' button towards the bottom-left of your post for adding more information to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code below (for getting edittext data):

```
br.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View v) {
               View ss = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.textt,null);
               final AlertDialog.Builder builderDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

                builderDialog.setView(ss)
                        .setPositiveButton("Print", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override 
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                EditText et = (EditText) ss.findViewById(E.id.editText);
                                listss.add(et.getText().toString());
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            } 
                        }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                        .setCancelable(false);

                AlertDialog alert = builderDialog.create();
                alert.show();
            } 
        });
```

Comment: yes,  I was actually not getting the data from my editText. :D

Comment: yeah...if you feel like it, you may want to 'accept' this answer

Comment: what do you mean accept, sorry it's my first time asking questions here.

Comment: :) .. There should be 'tick mark' towards the top-left of my answer..click it

Answer (score 0):

Here is the method in which i call on Button `button.setOnClickListener`

```
public void saveNote(View view){
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.add_new_note_layout);

    mTitle = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.titleID);
    mMessage = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.messageID);
    save = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);

    setFilePathll();

    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int titleLength = mTitle.getText().length();

            if(titleLength != 0){
                String title = mTitle.getText().toString();
                String msg = mMessage.getText().toString();

                helper.addNote(title, mFilePath, msg);

                dialog.dismiss();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Empty Message is not valid",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}
```

Here `helper.addNote(title, mFilePath, msg);` is the method which i declared in the database helper class to insert data.

you Should use `RecyclerView` for what you want instead of using '`ListView`'